# What do the red and yellow areas for AoE spells mean?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

When casting a spell with an area of effect, the targeting cursor is a red and a larger yellow circle.

[image]

What exactly do these two different circles mean? Is the effect weaker in the yellow circle?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The yellow area represents the *additional* area of effect granted by Intellect. The best part is that Friendly Fire *cannot* occur within this expanded zone, which allows you to do some very clever AE targetting and avoid hitting allies.